# OAuth partial disconnect

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

If I've socially connected a user to Google with permissions including `email`, is it possible to later perform a flow that let's the user revoke that `email` permission but not a full disconnect?

Or is the only way to disconnect totally and restart the OAuth flow with a new set of permissions?

Comment: A revoke on the auth will revoke everything there is no way to do incremental removal just incremental adding.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks. I thought as much. Please feel free to add an answer if this is the case.